# how to fix spelling mistakes in the man page

Tags: source-code, duplicity, helpfile, man

while reading the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/duplicity.1.html) of duplicity I found some minor spelling mistakes.

What is the easiest way to fix them, or have them fixed.

PS: I'm not a programmer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way would be to email the current maintainer listed within the man page.

In this case, it is Kenneth Loafman "kenneth@loafman.com"

Or, you could log into Launchpad and submit a bug to the [duplicity team](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/duplicity):

[image]

Personally, I would send the report to Launchpad as this may have a better chance of hitting a wider audience and getting the desired results. YMMV.

Comment: thinking about it the bug report is probably the way to go. thx